# How to compute $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} e^{-n}n^{-3/2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is following:

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{e^{-n}}{n^{3/2}}
$$

Can I get a precise expression of it? I mean the result. I have been working on it for a couple of days. It can be converted as follow according to polylogarithm on Wiki. I thought it might be useful.

$$
Li_{s}(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma (s)} \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{t^{s-1}}{\frac{e^{t}}{z}-1}dt,
$$
where 
$
Li_{s}(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{z^{k}}{k^{s}}
$

And the question at the beginning share the same expression. However, I still cannot work it out.

Comment: There is a closed form which involves the polylogarithm function which is probably not what you expect.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I noticed the way of using polylogarithm. But I do not think I can work that out with it. Can you be more specific? BTW, I add something to the question. Is it what you mean?

Comment: $\mathrm{Li}_{3/2}(1/e)$, is this your question?

Comment: @Did Exactly! Do you have any method to solve that?

Comment: Define "solve". To prove your sum is this, just plug $z=1/e$ and $s=3/2$ in the formula for $\mathrm{Li}_s(z)$. If you are asking for an equivalent formula involving only usual functions, there is probably none.

Comment: @Did I mean I want to get the result of the $Li_{3/2}(1/e)$. It should equal to a number, a constant.

Comment: Yeah, and there is probably no way to express this number in terms of usual functions.

Comment: @Did Well, then, fine...It seems that the only way is to use computer to calculate the answer. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **known** closed form for polylogarithms of argument $\dfrac1e~,$ other than the obvious $\text{Li}_1\bigg(\dfrac1e\bigg)=1-\ln(e-1).$